# Merge .img files using BAT script

Tags: android, batch-file

I am running into a 2gb file size barrier on my Galaxy S4 SD card for some reason.  The file system is exFAT so I dont know why there is an issue but there is.  I am pulling a system image from the phone but the image is in access of 2gb so i get the file too large error before the image is built.  To combat this i decided to split the image into two parts like so....

```
adb shell su -c "dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p%system% of=/%cardpath%/temp/system1.img bs=4096 count=393216"
adb shell su -c "dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p%system% of=/%cardpath%/temp/system2.img bs=4096 skip=393216 count=393216"
```

This will create two img files on the SD card.  System1.img and System2.img.
Now I want to combine them into one single file (System.img) but I can not combine them on the card like this....

```
adb shell su -c "dd if=/%cardpath%/temp/system1.img of=/%cardpath%/temp/system.img bs=4096 count=393216"
adb shell su -c "dd if=/%cardpath%/temp/system2.img of=/%cardpath%/temp/system.img bs=4096 count=393216 seek=393216"
```

.....because the final file will be larger than 2gb and result in the error described above.  So what I would like to do is combine the files on the PC rather than on the SD card of the phone but I do not know the BATCH command for this operation.  Can someone please help me with a BAT script to combine these two img files?

Thanks
Jimmie

Answer (score 1):

```
copy /b system1.img+system2.img=system.img
```

Answer (score 0):

`copy system1.img + system2.img system.img`

You can run this straight from the command line.

Or get Cygwin, which will give you a Bash shell to which you can issue the dd commands you already posted. But if you need it for this, it's probably overkill.

Comment: Wow, guess I was over thinking it.  I assumed there would need to be more logic involved.  I will test and report back.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay this did not work properly.  The command resulted in a very small file of a 115kb.  Should have been roughly 2.7gb final file.

Comment: Forgot the /b switch!!!

    copy /b system1.img+system2.img system.img 
.......works great.